# Prefixing unnested hits columns with "hits.{column name}" in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, unnest

Is there a way to prefix the columns which resulted from the `UNNEST(hits)` with `hits.` from the following query:

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT *
FROM `{project_id}.{dataset_id}.{table_name}`, UNNEST(hits)
```

For example, such that the result would contain a `hits.page` column instead of a `page` column.

Comment: `hits.page` is not a valid column name in BigQuery.  So, no, this is not possible.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is this also true for prefixing with `hits_` i.e., `hits_page`? From what I understand, I could do this with aliasing each column, is there a way to do this for all unnested hits columns or would I have to discover those names and alias them all separately?

Comment: . . Underscores are allowed, but that is not what you are asking.  What you want to do in this question cannot be done in BQ.

Answer (score 1):

Following the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas#column_names), I could find that the only characters valid for column names in BigQuery are letters (a-z, A-Z), numbers (0-9), or underscores (_). So, you couldn't name your column with "hits.page". Instead, you could probably use "hits_page" (using an underscore).

Comment: Please, accept this answer if this works for you. I'm glad if I could be of help.